# Как вывести результат файла php в переменную

Tags: php, html

Добрый день. Я делаю переменную

```
$My = file_get_contents('application\Views\Templates\Main\1.php');
```

Содержимое файла `1.php`:

```
какой-то html
<?php echo 11111;?>
```

В результате я вижу такой же код. А мне надо выполнить php и отдать ответ в переменную.

Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Надо использовать [буферизацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.outcontrol.php). Вкратце:

```
// включили буферизацию вывода
// с этого момента всё пойдёт не на вывод, а сохранится в буфере
ob_start();

// вставили и исполнили файл
include( 'application\Views\Templates\Main\1.php');

// всё, что накопилось в буфере отдали в переменную и очистили буфер
$My = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [ob_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-contents.php)